# Waterline BIGINT type with sails-mysql

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

I would like to know how can i define a bigint type in a waterline model using sails-mysql? Couldn't find any proper documentation about it. Seems like it doesn't support bigint types however i really need it. Trying to dig over the sourcecode i found something liek this: 
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql/blob/987f4674785970951bc52becdfdb479864106da1/helpers/private/schema/build-schema.js#L29
But it's still not working.

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {

        userId: {
            type: 'bigint',
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true,
        },
   }
};
```

This one still keeps creating an integer field in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok after digging through the source code a bit more i figured that i have to set an extra property called **size** for the field. Setting it to 64 will cause waterline to create a **BIGINT** field.

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {

        userId: {
            type: 'integer',
            size: 64, // waterline will translate this as bigint
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true,
        },
   }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work on Sails v1.0+. I get this error: The attribute `myAttribute` on the `myModel` model contains invalid properties. The property `size` isn't a recognized property.

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to use the following attributes:

```
{
   type: 'string',
   columnType: 'bigint'
}
```

This ignores Waterline data types and forces Postgres/MySQL column data type directly.

Comment: and why don't we use javascript's number type?

Comment: The issue is that the max "bigint" value is larger than the max JavaScript integer value, so it needs to be stored as a string. More info here: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1487 
This looks to be an area of development for Waterline/Sails, so might get fixed in future versions: https://trello.com/c/VgpoYb9j/132-figure-out-some-way-to-allow-sails-postgres-to-translate-bigint-attributes-to-numbers-automatically

Comment: Node.Js Number:
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER: 9007199254740991
Mysql BigInt Type:
Max Value: 9223372036854775807

I find it unlikely that anyone is going to store this much data, unless you're doing something really big. But indeed it is an issue that should be handled  by waterline. However depending on the case i would recommend to switch to a different ODM as waterline is really not suited for large scale applicaitons that would require this much data to be handled.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: I hadn't tested this thoroughly. It isn't working, after all.**

The property `size` isn't allowed for model attributes in Sails v1.0+, but this seems to work. I pulled it from the definition of the `createdAt` attribute in [the waterline library](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/lib/waterline.js) (line 485, as of this writing).

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    timeOfDay: {
      type: 'number',
      autoMigrations: { columnType: '_numbertimestamp' }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: By the way, this shouldn't be mySQL specific. I'm using postgreSQL.